# Does solr understand trailing space for autosuggestion?

Tags: autocomplete, solr, autosuggest

There seems to be no difference for solr to search for

```
'search/suggest/?q=print%20'
```

or

```
'search/suggest/?q=print'
```

Results are the same. But this is really important for autosuggestion.

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="spellcheck">
<lst name="suggestions">
<lst name="print">
<int name="numFound">5</int>
<int name="startOffset">0</int>
<int name="endOffset">6</int>
<arr name="suggestion">
<str>printer facsimile toner</str>
<str>print cartridge</str>
<str>printhead printhead</str>
<str>printer copier paper</str>
<str>printer kit</str>
</arr>
</lst>
<str name="collation">printer facsimile toner</str>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Upto My experience in Solr this will not consider trailing space but not sure about new version and new api..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
q=str:"print "
```

and

```
q=str:(print )
```

One of these should work (it depends on, how is your str field analysed).

Comment: I use keyword analyzer for suggest fields. Both your solutions dosn't work for me, seems solr din't understand `str` syntax